# Terminal Command for Uninstalling Programs

Tags: uninstall, installed-programs

What is the terminal command for easily uninstalling programs or software?

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt-get remove <program name here>
```

(or aptitude instead of apt-get, if you prefer it).

Comment: `sudo apt-get --purge remove <program name here>` will go farther and remove any configuration files the program created. Good if you're having problems with a program and just want to start over. Bad if you might want to re-install later and pick up where you were with that program.